# Mocha + Vue 2.6 unexpected token <

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js

I am trying to run a unit test in a Vue 2.6 app (needs to stay 2.6) with Mocha + Chai. Running dummy tests (eg. `expect(1 + 1).to.equal(2)`) works ok.

However, when I try mounting a Vue component inside the test file, it fails like so:

```
<template>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

So I guess I am missing something in my Mocha setup to resolve `.vue` files properly.

In my `.mocharc.yaml` I have just this:

```
require: [
  '@babel/register'
]
```

and my dev dependencies are:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.3.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "15.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.0.0",
    "husky": "8.0.0",
    "mocha": "8.4.0",
    "nx": "14.8.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.14"
  },
```

Any ideas what to add?